# Getting Last Index Value in JSON

Tags: javascript

What is Wrong in below code? getting last index value.in all JSON Object

```
    let arr = ['apple','banana','cherry'];
    let dataJson=[];
    let json={}
    console.log('lent',arr.length);
    for(var i = 0; i<arr.length;i++) {
        json.name=arr[i];
        json.type="fruit";
        dataJson.push(json);    
    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: If you want dataJson to have unique object with type nad name then you need to create object in a loop, otherwise they all will be same object.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the object reference within the array. In the last iteration the object will have `cherry` which is reflected in all objects passed within the array. Instead, use `Object.assign` to create new object.

```js
let arr = ['apple','banana','cherry'];
    let dataJson=[];
    let json={}
    for(var i = 0; i<arr.length;i++) {
        json.name=arr[i];
        json.type="fruit";
        dataJson.push(Object.assign({}, json));    
    }   

console.log(dataJson);
```

You can achieve the same functionality using `reduce`.

```js
let fruits = ['apple','banana','cherry'];

const output = fruits.reduce((a, fruit) => {
    a.push({"name": fruit, type: "fruit"});
    return a;
}, []);

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thanks @randomSoul

Comment: I don't think this is the correct use case for `Array.reduce`. I could certainly see `Array.map`, but there's isn't anything to reduce / accumulate here. If the OP was trying to get a count for the different types of fruit, I could totally see `reduce` here.

Answer (score 1):

I would use map to do it

```js
const arr = ['apple','banana','cherry']

const dataJson = arr.map(fruitName => ({name: fruitName, type: 'fruit'}))

console.log(dataJson)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to convert your array of `string` fruit names in to a JavaScript Object. Currently, your code is always overwritting the name property with every iteration. I would suggest *pushing an object* in every iteration instead.

```js
let arr = ['apple','banana','cherry'];
let dataJson = [];
console.log('lent',arr.length);
for(var i = 0; i <arr.length; i++) {
  dataJson.push({name: arr[i], type: 'fruit'} )
}

console.log(dataJson);



// Modern way of doing it with Array.map
const data = ['apple','banana','cherry'].map( d => ( { name: d, type: 'fruit' } ) );
console.log(data);
```

In other news, `JSON` is a string. You're working with a JavaScript Object.